# Question about score notes

Tags: flute, bansuri

Quick question — I have a bansuri flute, and I was wondering do you know the notes on this score?

[image: Pokemon SM/USUM - Summoning Solgaleo/Lunala. A short tune for two flutes, mainly playing a perfect fourth apart.]

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What is it about the notes that you want to know?

Comment: Seconding what @ElementsinSpace said. Do you have trouble with reading the notes (unfamiliar symbol)? Or do you not know how to physically play them on your instrument? And which ones? Please make it clear what exactly it is that you need help with.

Comment: @Divizna yes I'm having trouble reading the notes

Comment: There are many resources to learn the pitches of the staff; try https://www.musictheoryacademy.com/how-to-read-sheet-music/treble-clef/

Comment: https://music.stackexchange.com/q/102124/78419 might be helpful too.

Comment: @AndyBonner Did they just... leave out d' and g''? Tut tut.

Comment: @AndyBonner do you know the notes on this score?

Comment: @Daniel I do know what the note names are; for instance, the first one in both parts is C#. I don't have any idea how to play them on bansuri. If you're not sure about the letter names, try https://www.musictheory.net/lessons/10 (or the page I linked earlier).